# how to know if the data is clicked or enabled in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a location tracker app, and one of my requirements is to send/check the location every time data will be available.

Right now what I have is that the application is running on the background and I just set a timer that every after this hour it will check if data is available, which I believe is not the appropriate way.

It's something like this:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000){

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        if(dataIsEnabled())
        {
            doThis();
        }
        else
        {
            doThis();
        }
    }.start();
```

Is there a way to know if that data button is clicked? thank you

Comment: Have you checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply this is already running in background but been wandering if there's other way to know if data button is clicked? but not overriding it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see where is your button, or how the button interacts with your timer... Does the clock start if I click the button?